# Magento 2 order is shipped twice on sales_order_save_commit_after event

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order

I'm trying to ship an order automatically everytime an order is placed, just with event `sales_order_save_commit_after` works, I tried `sales_order_place_after` and it throws me the error of "No such entity with order ID".

Anyway,I have the event in etc/events.xml , because in frontend it does not run.
However, the order is shipped twice, here you can see:

[image]

How can I just run once this event, so I can have just one shipment?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the event `checkout_submit_all_after` instead. It triggers just once after the order is created.